# android: Unable to build application - classes.dex (Access is denied)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

works fine if I don't include a particular jar library. It used to work earlier not sure why this is happening now.

Using Intellij Idea13

```
Android Packager:[*] java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...intermediate_artifacts\*\classes.dex (Access is denied)
```

Comment: able to build using gradle